# GetType() method call on Automation Variable's Value causing runbook to fail and suspend

Tags: powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I'm trying to print the type of the value of Azure Automation Account's Automation variable using the below code in an automation runbook of type **Powershell**.

```
$var1 = ((Get-AzureRmAutomationVariable -Name "ArrayVar" -ResourceGroupName "automation-ps-rg" -AutomationAccountName "automation-ps-aa").Value).GetType()
$var1
```

I'm seeing that this causes runbook to fail and retry for 3 times and eventually fail with the below message.

```
Suspended
The runbook job was attempted 3 times, but it failed each time.
```

Any reason why this could be failing?

Thanks!

Comment: You might be calling `GetType()` on `$null`.  That is, the result of the code inside the brackets may not produce any object(s).  What do you get if you remove `GetType()`?

Comment: I'm seeing the value correctly when I remove the get type method call

Comment: This also happens when I replace the Get-AzureRmAutomationVariable cmdlet with Get-AutomationVariable cmdlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you need just the type name, try `(...).GetType().FullName`.

Something seems to be broken with writing System.Type objects to job streams, so try to select the properties you are actually interested in, not the entire object.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Posted the feedback here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/34090405-gettype-method-call-on-automation-variable-s-val